# Mongoose: Update and $pull from an array of references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My User model includes:

```
{_id: "GenericMongoId",
 friends: [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref:'User'}]
}
```

I am creating a function such that after you delete a user, all the references to that user in all users friends arrays are removed as well.

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function (err, user) {
   user.remove(function(err) {
       User.update(({friends: req.params.id}),{$pull: {friends:req.params.id}},    function(err, data){
      console.log(err, data)...
```

When I run the function and pass in the id, it for some reason seems to only delete one friend reference.  I assume I'm missing something, but my googling isn't finding it.

Comment: Why is there this extra parenthesis here  User.update((?

Comment: There's additional code beyond the ellipsis

Comment: You certainly don't need those extra parenthesis  ({friends: req.params.id})

Comment: Removed...same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh, just add the multi option

```
User.update({friends: req.params.id},
{$pull: {friends:req.params.id}},{multi:true}...
```

Comment: Oh sweet and we are in the promise land of deletion

Answer (score 0):

According to the Mongoose documentation, findById search for a single document by it's id.

> Finds a single document by id.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

You can achieve the desired result by using Model.update.